# Get other json value from another value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am retrieving the maximum and minimum from a long JSON response. I managed to retrieve those values, but I want to retrieve also the date of those values. The structure of the JSON response is:

```
?({"channel":{"id":XXXXX,"name":"XXXXXX","field1":"Temperature","field2":"Humidity","created_at":"2015-11-03T13:12:06Z","updated_at":"2015-11-15T12:07:37Z","last_entry_id":142},"feeds":[{"created_at":"2015-11-14T21:06:16Z","entry_id":136,"field1":"0"},{"created_at":"2015-11-14T21:06:39Z","entry_id":137,"field1":"25"},{"created_at":"2015-11-14T21:06:59Z","entry_id":138,"field1":"24.05"},{"created_at":"2015-11-14T21:07:13Z","entry_id":139,"field1":"24.45"},{"created_at":"2015-11-14T21:08:16Z","entry_id":140,"field1":"24.45"},{"created_at":"2015-11-15T12:06:18Z","entry_id":141,"field1":"24.5"},{"created_at":"**2015-11-15T12:07:37Z**","entry_id":142,"field1":"**21.4**"}]})
```

In ** are the values that I retrieve in the jquery code. And this is my jquery code:

```
$.getJSON('http://api.thingspeak.com/channels/'+channel+'/field/1.json?callback=?',
                {key: read_API_key, days: "1"},
                function(data) {
                    var temp_vals = [];
                    var temp_vals_date = [];
                    $.each(data.feeds, function() {
                        temp_vals.push(parseFloat(this.field1));
                        temp_vals_date.push(this.created_at);
                    });
                    var temp_max = Math.max.apply(Math, temp_vals);
                    var temp_min = Math.min.apply(Math, temp_vals);                 
                    $('#temp1_max').text(temp_max + ' ºC');
                    $('#temp1_min').text(temp_min + ' ºC');

                    console.log("Temp vals: "+temp_vals);
                    console.log("Temp vals date: "+temp_vals_date);

                    console.log("Max val: "+temp_max);
                    console.log("Min val: "+temp_min);
                }
            );
```

The console show the correct values for all the data, but the question is: Are there any way to link the maximum value with the date?, or find in which position of the array is the maximum value after doing the math function?

I think this shouldn't be difficult but I am trying to find something in Internet and I didn't find anything. I'm a little messed up with the JSON responses.

Comment: Not that this really has nothing to do with JSON. By the time your code is processing it, it's not JSON anymore.

Comment: So, cannot be retrieved the field that matches with another field using JSON? Should be done using Jquery and processing the array, isn't?

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a **string**, you're not dealing with JSON. In the above, you're dealing with an array of objects. The JSON **string** has already been parsed into an array of objects for you, by jQuery. If jQuery hadn't done it for you, your first step would have been `JSON.parse`, after which (again) you wouldn't be dealing with JSON anymore.

Comment: just sort and get it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there any way to link the maximum value with the date?

Yes, you could keep track of the entry rather than just the value. That could well be more efficient than your current code, which has to take three passes through arrays where one would do.

> , or find in which position of the array is the maximum value after doing the math function?

Yes, in ES2015 you could do that with `Array#find`; in ES5 and earlier, with `Array#some`. But we don't need to find it retrospectively.

Here's the one-pass approach:

```
$.getJSON('http://api.thingspeak.com/channels/' + channel + '/field/1.json?callback=?', {
        key: read_API_key,
        days: "1"
    },
    function(data) {
        var max = null, min = null;
        $.each(data.feeds, function() {
            var val = parseFloat(this.field1);
            if (!max || max.val < val) {
                max = {created_at: this.created_at, val: val};
            }
            if (!min || min.val > val) {
                min = {created_at: this.created_at, val: val};
            }
        });
        $('#temp1_max').text(max.val + ' ºC');
        // Use max.created_at here (or something like that)
        $('#temp1_min').text(min.val + ' ºC');
        // Use min.created_at here (or something like that)
    }
);
```

If you wanted, you could also keep track of the `entry_id` by just adding it to the objects we create. Or you could just add `val` to your existing objects. Or re-parse each time.

---

If you can change the other end, which is giving you this data, I'd suggest changing it so `field1` is a **number**, not a string containing a number, so you don't have to do that `parseFloat` stuff.

Comment: Thanks, that solve my problem and I've learnt how to do it for the next time.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over the `data.feeds` array to look for max temperature value and when found, get the date.
Like:

```
var max_date = '';
for (var i = 0; i < data.feeds.length; i++) {
  if( data.feeds[i].field1 == temp_max ) {
    max_date = data.feeds[i].created_at;
    break;
  }
};

console.log(max_date);
```

Put it after `$.each(data.feeds ...` ends.

Comment: So yet *another* pass through the array. Sure, it probably doesn't matter (the array's not going to be millions of entries long), but it's just so unnecessary.

Comment: This works too, but I prefer the other options to learn how manipulate in long values. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

```
var sorted = data.feeds.sort(function(a, b){return +a.field1 - b.field1;);
var min = sorted[0];
var max = sorted[sorted.length-1];
```

Comment: This does, of course, do a lot of repeated `parseFloats` and modifies the original array. Which could be fine, although in particular the `.shift` and `.pop` seem like unnecessarily destructive operations. Also uses different rules for numeric parsing that the OP's original code (again, though, unlikely to matter).

Comment: It *compares* them. But if it were necessary to use `parseFloat`, that would be an easy change.

Comment: There's no need for your edit, `-` coerces both operands to numbers.

Comment: I agree only with complexity, sort is `O(nlogn)`, while task is linear :) But readability is better in this case. I don't think this API returns thousands data points..

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have type casts, it's a loosely typed language. Type *coercion* differs from `parseFloat` in a couple of ways: 1. Coercion sees `""` as `0` instead of `NaN`. 2. Coercion requires the value *as a whole* to be a number, `parseFloat` ignores any trailing non-numeric chars (e.g., `+"123any"` is `NaN`, but `parseFloat("123any")` is `123`). In this use case, I'd use coercion or coercion with a special case for `""`. Well, no, I'd fix the other end so it sent numbers to start with. :-)

Comment: heh, that's funny, I was editing that in as you posted your question